# Form submission recognition: works only when a textarea is active. What do I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where Ajax updates the feed every once in a while. Under each post there's a textarea for a reply. JQuery/Ajax can post the reply to the database without any problems when the textarea is active. I press the submit button and everything goes well.

However, if I click somewhere else on the page and the textarea becomes inactive, the submit button doesn't work anymore like it should: it submits the form to root and doesn't run the Ajax function.

Can you figure out what's wrong in my code? Thank you for your help!

There are as many forms as there are messages on the pages. The forms look like this:

```
<form class="reply-form">
<textarea id="reply-11123" name="comment" class="plain-editor"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Reply" />
<input type="hidden" value="URL HERE" name="url" /> 
</form>
```

Ajax code (at `<head>`) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.reply-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
    message_data = $form.find('textarea[name="comment"]').val(),
    url = $form.find('input[name="url"]').val();

    var postData = {};
    var prefix = 'data';
    postData[prefix + '[message]'] = message_data;
    var posting = $.post(url, postData);

    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know if this submit handler even fires? How do you know that it's POSTing or not? You immediately prevent the default behavior. You don't have any logging/debugging code in there to know whether that's working. Also, you aren't handling the success/failure callbacks of `$.post`. Try this syntax: `$.post({...}).done(function(result) { ...}).fail(function(xhr, status, message) { // log or alert });`. It will help you if instead something is failing on the server-side.

Comment: Also, if your forms are being added to the page dynamically then you need a different event binding: `$(document).on('submit', 'form.reply-form', function (event) { ... });`

Comment: Thanks for comments. If I write something to the reply field and press immediatly submit the submit handler fires. I know this because the replys appear on the page. BUT if I write something and click elsewhere on the page and THEN click submit, the handler doesn't fire. So basically debugging the handler doesn't solve the problem now. I try the event binding you suggested.

Comment: Your code `$(document).on('submit', 'form.reply-form', function (event) { ... });` did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Well that was a lucky guess then! I've converted my comment to an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your forms are being added to the page dynamically then you need a different event binding that will attach itself to all current and *future* forms. The current binding you have is called a **direct** binding, but what you really need is a **delegated** binding. A different usage of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will give you that:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.reply-form', function (event) {
     ... 
});
```